# How do you force a Console App Project to include a folder in the build?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

Let's say you create a C# console application, in Visual Studio, and within the application you create a folder called "Content".  How would you force the project to include this folder during the build?

What I mean by this, is I want this "Content" folder to be present in /bin/Debug when I build the project.  Currently, this new "Content" folder is not being outputted/created in the /bin/Debug folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the project, select Properties > Build Events, then put the following script in the Post-build event command line:

```
xcopy /E "$(ProjectDir)\Content" "$(TargetDir)\Content\*"
```

Screenshot:

[image: Project Properties]

This script is stored in your .csproj file, so the build will work in the TFS Build Agent as well.

Answer (score 6):

For each file within your Content folder, you should be able to set the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy Always, in the Properties panel.

[image: Screenshot]

I don't think you can apply this property to a folder directly, so if you're only looking to include blank folder, it might just be easier to get the console app to [create the blank folder you require at runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you have files in the folder, you would just set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".  If you don't really have any files, I usually just add a ReadMe.txt